# primitive root of 1 in algebraically closed set

Tags: field-theory

Let $K$ be a field, and character is $p$.
If $p$ does not divide $n$, primitive $n$-th root of unity exists in the algebraically closed extension of $K$.

I want to find example, where $p$ devides $n$,there is no unity in the algebraically closed extension of K, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $K$ is any field of characteristic $p$ then the following equality holds in $\overline{K}[x]$:

$x^p-1=(x-1)^p$

And so $1$ is the only root of unity of order $p$. So there are no primitive roots of order $p$ in $\overline{K}$.